# Setting up database for the first time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very much fresh in using Ruby on Rails. I have cloned a Git repo and trying to set up a PostgreSQL database in my local machine(Win 10).

```
Ruby version- 2.4.10
Rails - 5.2.0
```

I am using the below command

`rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=development`

Error output:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
D:/ruby/reserves/config/environments/development.rb:41:in `block in <top (required)>'
D:/ruby/reserves/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
D:/ruby/reserves/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

In `database.yml` file there are three environments has been declared - Development/Production/test

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: reserves-dev
  username:****
  password:****
  host: localhost
```

/config/environments/development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Email
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:address],
    port: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:port],
    user_name: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:username],
    password: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:password],
    domain: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:domain],
    authentication: :plain
  }
  # NOTE: For email need to have authentication :login (instead of :plain) and
   # the tls: true param, otherwise the server times out on password reset request. 

  Rails.application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :ignore_crawlers => %w{Googlebot bingbot},
  :ignore_exceptions => ['ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest'] + ExceptionNotifier.ignored_exceptions,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[ERROR] ",
    :sender_address => %{"Arc Reserves" <noreply@*****.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{info@****.com}
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

How can I set the environment variable to `development` for setting the database in my local?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with development.rb.

Comment: I think the error is because it not getting the env variable, if you have not set any env variable please search for `ENV` through out the project and set all of those by creating `.env` file in your root folder of project.

Comment: @user681    I can see `puma` installed `environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }` There is no .env in root folder.

Comment: Okay great so you need to create a file `.env` and then add `RAILS_ENV='what_ever_value'`. Most probably its value here will be you environment as in 'production' or 'test' or 'development'

Comment: I guess it's already referring to `development` because if I just use `rake db:setup` then it goes to `development.rb` but what I don't understand is that there  is already database.yml and all the configuration values but it is not fetching those.

Comment: Check in the error message its pointing to line:41 so have you added the smtp details?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because of the lines like:

```rb
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:mailer][:address]
```

Could you change it to something like that?

```rb
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mailer, :address)
```

Comment: Also the OP can ensure that the credentials file has the appropriate keys/values in teh correct environment.It looks like the app is using the newer secure credentials.  https://blog.engineyard.com/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2#:~:text=Your%20text%20editor%20will%20open,yml.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Yes correct. The master.key is missing as it is not in the repo and it should not be versioned for security reason but there is an encrypted credentials.yml.enc file.

Comment: Then you need to get the master key from a coworker in order to access the credentials. I encountered this erro in app that I worked on that used secure creds.